# Do I need to use npm init every time I create a new project?

Tags: reactjs, json, npm, syntax

I saw people explaining that `npm init` is necessary to create the `package.json` file. But in my last practice project I forgot to use `npm init` and the `package.json` file was created when I used `npx create-react-app ...`

Can someone help me to understand this, please?

Comment: No, because: 1. in the general case you could just create your own package file, there's nothing very special about it; and 2. in this case CRA creates it for you.

Comment: only if you start a project from scratch without a package.json, otherwise you don't need npm init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package.json file is a file where you specify the name of the application ,the version,  the licence the dependancies the app needs etc.It is not necessary to do npm init before spinning up a new react project as it comes with a package json file that has the project dependancies and scripts to start/run the app .You can just modify the package json file that comes with the react app to fit your needs.